# How to Fix 'There has been a critical error on your website' for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I currently update my WordPress to 5.3 and the below error shows up. I encounter the below problem then I change wp-config.php settings to TRUE, to be able to see the below error, pls help me so many errors shows up

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function electro_get_home_v1_meta() in /home/cjabiaxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/electro/template-homepage-v1.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/cjabiaxx/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(98): include() #1 /home/cjabiaxx/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once(’/home/cjabiaxx/...’) #2 /home/cjabiaxx/public_html/index.php(17): require(’/home/cjabiaxx/...’) #3 {main} thrown in /home/cjabiaxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/electro/template-homepage-v1.php on line 19